# How can I position a div on top of everything, but in relation to another element on page?

Tags: jquery, css, html, positioning

I am wanting to position my div on top of everything, but just under my menu bar.  Very similar to the div that shows up when you click your username here at stackoveflow.  I've not had much luck using absolute positioning, though I might be doing it incorrectly.

Here is the code example: http://jsfiddle.net/DR8H9/2/

My issue is the div only appears directly under the link if the width is set to an exact size.  If someone were to change the size of their browser's window it no longer would be correct.

```
.diva
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.thisguy
{
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 75px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  left: 410px;

}
```

Comment: myapologiesIveeditedmypost.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some code on **JSFiddle**, check it out: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/J2dqY/1/)

Basically what i'm doing is in the **CSS**:

```
.panel{
    position:relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:grey;
  }

  .box{
     position:relative;
     height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
     left: 235px;
     background-color:red;
  }
```

And in the **HTML**

```
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

You have to be more specific how you want this box to appear (relative to other classes, or absolute). But this is the general idea.

Comment: I've tried this but I have a similar problem where if the user modifies the width of their browser window then the box no longer shows under where I want it too.

Comment: Can you check if this is what you want? Check out JSFiddle, its updated.

Comment: So what if my text isn't in an absolute location... such as `margin: 0 auto;` or `text-align: center;` ?

Comment: Then i would suggest to put the text_div and the box_div inside a container_div. In this way they will be centered in the same way. You can still hide the box_div with the click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Then using jQuery get the position of the link that you click and then set the position of the div

Then something like this should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.thisguy').hide();

$('.diva a').click(function() {

var pos=$(this).position();
$('.thisguy').css({'top':pos.top+25+"px",'left':pos.left-1+"px"});

$('.thisguy').toggle();

});

$(window).resize(function() {  
     $('.thisguy').hide();
});  

});
```

if someone was to resize their window, then I would use jQuery to hide the div(s), or you are going to have to try and do some coding to check the resize and then reposition the div again.

try this http://jsfiddle.net/trekmp/kJaEc/

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<div id="first"><div></div><div>
```

and the css

```
#first{position:relative; width:100%; height:20px; background-color:green; }
#first div{position:absolute; top:100%; left:50px; height:30px; width:30px; background-color:red;}
```

You can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tR9rg/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution using your own code:

[JSFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/UvvBS/5/)

Basically all you were missing was the `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` for your `.thisguy` class. Which will center it on the page. Now if you add more links... we will probably need to look at that...